# Trouble with appropriate controller actions for assigning a user to a patient

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still a little new to rails so forgive me if this is really easy.

I am working on a demo CRM that allows a user to create and have many clients. However, I also want that same user to be able to assign other users to work on that client. Once added, any user can add other users to a client. I am having difficulty with what the appropriate controller actions would be to allow that.

I currently have the has_many through: relationships as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cases
  has_many :clients, through: :cases
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cases
  has_many :users, through: :cases
end

class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Currently, I want it so that when you see the client page (show.html.erb), you can add people to @client.users.

I have this so far:

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    @users = User.all
  end

  def add_user_to
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    @selected_user = (params[:user_id])
    @client.users << @selected_user
  end
end
```

I'm using a route for post method for add_user_to_client_path

The form I'm using to submit is in the show.html.erb as follows:

```
<%= form_tag(add_user_to_client_path, method: :post) do %>
  <%= select_tag options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, "id", "first_name") %>
  <%= submit_tag "Add Client Member", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to what I can do? I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to find user, change this line:

```
@selected_user = (params[:user_id])
```

to

```
@selected_user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

**UPDATE:**

You need give a name to `select_tag`

```
<%= select_tag 'user_id', options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, "id", "first_name") %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When I change that, it throws me an error saying "Could not find a User without and ID". What I'm trying to do is pass a user ID from a drop down list, pass it to selected_user and then add that user to client.users